# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^x arctan(x)}{y} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^x arctan(x)}{y} $$

Hello I am new to multi-variable calculus and facing difficulty solving these type of question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{e^x \arctan(x)}{y}$. Let $a \ne 0$ and consider $f(x,ax)$.

Show that $f(x,ax) \to 1/a$ for $x \to 0$.

Can you now conclude that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^x \arctan(x)}{y}$ does not exist ?

Comment: it becomes $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x arctan(x)}{ax}$ Now can we use LHopital's rule at this stage ? Using that I am getting 1/a.. and the limit won't exist since it is path dependent

Comment: Yes, you can use  LHopital's rule. Yes, the limit does not exist since it is path dependent .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use Taylor series around $x=0$
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=x+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$e^x \tan ^{-1}(x)=x+x^2+O\left(x^3\right)=x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which let you considering $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^x \tan(x)}{y}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x}{y}$$